# Image in Equations as $P('image')\ge c$

Tags: math-mode, graphics

I try to plug an image in one equation as follows:

$$P('image')\ge c$$

How to write this code in Latex?

I used this way in [Image in Equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444922/image-in-equations). But the `$\ge c$` part will be too high/low for the brackets $P(...)$.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% for the second solution

\usepackage{duckuments}% for the images

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
P(
\begin{gathered}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-duck})\ge c
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you can show the current output and explain what is the desired output. I do not see `$\ge c$` in your code example.

Comment: I added the vertical-alignment tag because I assumed that by "not in right position" you meant that the image was too high or low. If that isn't the case, please clarify.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Exactly. My image is too high for the brackets $P(...)$.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOBmt.jpg

Comment: I not know if I have understand your question. You can decrease the image and fit it with the rounded brackets.

Answer (score 4):

I have used [graphbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphbox) package with the option `c` (center) instead of `graphicx`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{duckuments}% for the images
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
P\left(\,\includegraphics[align=c,scale=0.5]{example-image-duck}\,\right)
\geq c
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, never heard of `graphbox`!

Comment: I have updated the link to the landing page for the package on ctan, hope that's ok.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner You are...always ....welcome :-).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner You can see that: *For example, changing the vertical alignment is convenient for
using graphics as elements of (mathematical) formulae*.